# After updating Fedora, my drives are switched between /dev/sda and /dev/sdb

Tags: linux, filesystems, hard-drive

I have two hard drives:

- internal (SATA)
- external (USB).

Before updating Linux (Fedora), the internal drive was in `/dev/sda` and the external drive in `/dev/sdb`. Now, after updating, those two are switched.

How do I move the internal drive back to /dev/sda?

Answer (score 1):

Put simply: You don't. If you want persistent names to identify hard disks, you use the disk ID with the symlinks provided in `/dev/disk/by-id`.

Answer (score 0):

You can statically assign /dev nodes using udev rules, this should work for you if you wish to switch /dev/sdb and /dev/sda.

http://www.thelinuxdaily.com/2010/01/statically-assign-dev-nodes-to-hardware-devices-in-linux/